# Load images using AsyncImageView to ImageView width

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios7

I have used `AsyncImageView` for loading the images from url. But the image is not loading to the image view width. Below is my code.

```
{
    AsyncImageView *asyImage;
    asyImage = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [asyImage loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [propertyImage addSubview:asyImage];
    propertyImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NSString * urlString = @"http://img-paragon.sandicor.com/ParagonImages/Property/Q1/SANDICOR/150016147/0/0/0/729a48630a22f4436d3e45e671bb3548/1/e2d30ecd1633ebc3b6b1f6acbcc77331/150016147.JPG";
NSData *dataCoverImg = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
UIImage *imgLocation = [UIImage imageWithData:dataCoverImg];
self.image = [imgLocation resizedImage:self.propertyImage.frame.size interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationMedium]; // Can we resize image using UIImage+Resize equel to imageview size

self.urlForTesting=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
 CGRect frame = self.propertyImage.bounds; AsyncImageView *asyImage;
asyImage=[[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
asyImage.imageURL =self.urlForTesting;


asyImage.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
asyImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
asyImage.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
[self.propertyImage addSubview:asyImage];

self.mySecondImageView.image = self.image; // set directly to asyncimage view with aspect mode AspectFill
self.myThirdImageView.image = self.image; //Set to normal Image view with aspect Mode ScaleToFill
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
```

in this code i used three image view samples for you all of those get full image according to image view size

[image: ImageView width management]

Comment: if your url string has escapes character then you have to encode it using  url =[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: The image is loading but it's doesn't match the width of image view

Comment: you want to fill imageview with full width?

Comment: you have to set UIImageView scale mode ScaleToFill to save distortion set AspectFill rather than AspectFit

Comment: in my application when i need imageview filled with full image i used Scale To Fill .

Comment: behaviour of aspect fill mode as i also mentioned in code comment

Comment: You have to set mode for imageview not for container view

Comment: here is my complet code ' CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size=propertyImage.frame.size;
    AsyncImageView *asyImage;
    asyImage=[[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [asyImage loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:test]];
    asyImage.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    asyImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    asyImage.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    [propertyImage addSubview:asyImage];'

Comment: let me check in my application

Comment: Can you share yours testing url to do actual implementation? i made a demo application

Comment: I add a screen shot of my demo application output now kindly clear me what you want from all of three image views top one , Middle one or third one ?

Comment: Since i don't know the size of the Image provide by the server,  I just want that if the size of image provide by the server is small or large it should get totally fit in mu UIImageview, Lets suppose if the imageview width=304 and heigth=218, will the image which url i provided will fix in it?

Comment: if you share with me your email id i will send you demo application. in my code example you can get this output

Comment: No Problem Brother  Always Welcome